# How can I remove the field name from Django's default 2-line form field error messages in {{ form.errors }}?

Tags: django, django-forms

As an example, I'm using the following in a user signup form template:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

If I try to register a new user with an existing username I (as expected) get this two-line error message:

```
username
A user with that username already exists.
```

I would be perfectly happy with this message if I could just drop the first line ("username") so that the two-line message becomes a one-line message like this:

```
A user with that username already exists.
```

I know the fieldname sometimes qualifies line 2 of the default error message (eg "This field is required"), but I can use

```
error_messages = {'required': "mycustommessage" }
```

in my form definitions to change "This field is required" to "Username is required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the output like this:

```
{% for error in form.username.errors %}
    {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```